# Conflicting scale in layouts between AutoCAD and QGIS?

Tags: qgis, scale, layouts, autocad

I have a recurrent problem.

Whenever I import data from **AutoCAD** (through *dxf*, properly referenced) into **QGIS** and then compose a layout at the same scale as the layout I had in **AutoCAD**, they appear to be at different sizes.

Not a huge difference, but definitely noticeable.

I checked, for instance, the size of a random line, and it's the same in both programs, the problem is only in the layout.

[image]

Comment: I'm having a hard time picturing what you're describing. How about adding a screenshot to illustrate your issue?

Comment: Added one image that hopefully shows the differences.

Comment: measuring the map or graphical legend, which one is the correct?

Comment: I'm sure the correct one is AutoCAD, but i can't seem to find what's causing that on QGIS.

Comment: It looks like QGIS is just zoomed out a bit relative to the AutoCAD layout. Can you change the scale on the print composer map?

Comment: I guess you are note experience a change in the coordinates, so in both pictures the elements are in the coordinates where they are supposed to be. So, it is a matter of the production of the output, a pdf or a paper. There is a lot of care about the units you need to care about in both software in the production stepts of blueprints, and there is the hard test of a wooden rule ate the end. Could you tell us more about your procedure?

Comment: What is the scale you want to achieve in your example? Lets start with autocad. What are the units of you model space? what are the units of your paper? what are the scale of the view in your paper space? and finnaly how does it look the print window what sclae is stated there?

Comment: Then you could tell us alsmot the same about the print composer options in Qgis. If the problem is noticeable, one of the plots has something wrong in the production options.

Comment: Now, I've plotted both layouts and here's what i found:
AutoCAD shows the correct scale when measured with the old ruler.
In QGIS, both map and graphical scale are off (20% smaller).

Comment: Also coordinates are the same in both programs, and outside of the layout composer, everything measures up fine in QGIS (length, coordinates, etc).
So I must be doing something odd in the composer...

Comment: You're not providing enough information for us to help you. For example, don't just tell us that the scales are the same; tell us what *is* the scale of the layout in each program. Edit your question with all the information @Marco asked for, then maybe we'll be able to figure out what's going wrong.